# View only part of an image?

Tags: theming

I am not sure if this can be done with core or Module settings, or require some tricky CSS work.

I have an image that is part of a slideshow that goes all the way across the page no matter how wide or narrow it is.  The images are around 1,140 x 698 pixels.

However, I want up to 700 px (on the page) to be visible.

So when the window is the same width as the image, the entire image is seen because it is only 698px tall.

When the window is **wider** than the image width (e.g. 1920 px and the image is 1,140px) the image is scaled up so the width is the 1920px and the hieight is increased proportionally, but the visible height is still only 700 px, and everything extra (below) is cropped off.

When the window is **more narrow** than the image width (e.g. 900px and the image is 1,140px) the image stays in proportion and the height will be less than 700px. Thus the entire picture will be seen.

Scaling will only stretch the image.

I am thinking that this will have to be done with some clever CSS work, but I am at a loss to what it can be called for me to look it up. It may also require JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a custom CSS issue, not theming or modules related. You can install a module that lets you enter CSS code through Drupal interface and it gets applied after the theme, if you're not using a subtheme or your own custom theme where you can add the custom CSS rule for your image. It can be done with the clip-path property, get help in the CSS area for that.

Comment: [CSS object-fit Property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) and [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) is what you need. Voting to close as it has nothing to do with Drupal.

Comment: I thought it would be a CSS and not a Drupal-specific question unless there was some module or something in the core.  Thank you for the suggestions.  They give me  a direction.